# how to send post data in jquery using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, .post

i have a simple form and i want that the as the input field losses the focus the event is fired which will check the content if and replies accordingly to that

```
$("document").ready(function()
    $("#txt_Email").blur(function() {                   
        var email=$("#txt_Email").val();                   
        $.post('ajax/tester.php', {chk:email}, function(data) {
            alert(data) ;
        });
    });
});
```

so i have done till this but it's showing nothing: no error, no output. i am using `jquery 1.9.1` and  i also want to know how to check the value of post data on the `ajax/tester.php` page

Right now i am doing this

```
$tochk=isset($_POST['chk'])?$_POST['chk']:null;

echo $tochk;
```

Comment: first make sure `email` contains a value, then debug on the php side to make sure it runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$(function(){
    $("#txt_Email").blur(function() {                   
        var email=$("#txt_Email").val(); 
        alert('email: ' + email);
        var jqxhr = $.post('ajax/tester.php', {chk:email});
        jqxhr.done(function(data) { alert(data); });
        jqxhr.fail(function() { alert("error"); });
    });
});

window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
    var errorText = 'message: ' + errorMessage + '\nurl: ' + url + '\nline: ' + line;
    alert(errorText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$("document").ready(function()
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

You need to refer to the `document` object, not the string `"document"`. Using your same code with this small change it works fine. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YjEMd/. Note that this example has change the URL of the Ajax and the format of the data being posted so that it can work inside jsFiddle's sandbox. Also the `$(document).ready(...)` bit is done for you in the background.